# Foreign key insertion against 10k records

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database, mariadb

I have a table `A` with 200 records and table `B` with 10K, The table `A` have a unique code which is `varchar` (cannot be changed) and suppose calls `A_code`. Table `B` have that code against every row (Means 10k records).

Means the relation is one to many.

How can I add a foreign key to the table `B` agaist `A_code` column?

phpMyAdmin throws an error when I want to create foreign key,

> Error creating foreign key on ccg_code (check data types)

Comment: The columns must have the same data type in both tables.

Comment: you mean table `B`'s column `A_code` and table `A`'s `id` ?

Comment: Show your SQL code. I mean A_code in both tables.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs if the data type of the referenced column differs, e.g. column in 1st table is defined as int, while column in 2nd table is defined as bigint.

If they have the same data type, please also check if signed/unsigned is the same, for character fields also character set and collation must be the same.